# Did remember/ remembered

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-tense, sentence-choice

There is a sentence from GoT: `And perhaps the dragon did remember, but Dany could not`

What the differences between sentences:

> And perhaps he did remember, but she could not
>
> And perhaps he remembered, but she could not

Is it correct to use `did + Verb`?

Comment: There was a similar question answered on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verbed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiomatic usage of ***[do/does/did](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv298.shtml)*** to add emphasis to the verb they precede:

> We do not normally use do or does in affirmative sentences, but ***we can use them for emotive or contrastive emphasis when we feel strongly about something:***
>
> - *She thinks he doesn't love her, ***but he does love her***. He really does!
> - ***You do look pretty*** in that new outfit! Quite stunning!
> - Are you all right? ***You do look a bit pale***. Do please sit down.
> - I don't see very much of my old friends now, ***but I do still email them.***
>     Was that a joke? I do believe you're teasing me!*
>
> When we are using the auxiliaries do and does for contrastive or emotive emphasis like this, we give them extra stress in pronunciation to make them sound louder, longer or higher in tone.

(www.bbc.co.uk)

Comment: Just wanted to add one point for the second question._Is it correct to use did + Verb?_ **Yes.** Whenever *did + verb* is used, the verb must be in it's **base form**.