# Once, he did dive for cover but he soon reappeared and continued his activities

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Once, he did dive for cover but he soon reappeared and continued his activities.

Does 'did dive for cover' mean 'seclude'?

Answer (score 1):

*He dived for cover* = he quickly moved into a place where he couldn't be seen.

The addition of *did* emphasises the verb. "It's true he hid once, but he didn't stay hidden for long."

See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174223/did-remember-remembered).

Answer (score 1):

To dive for cover is to throw yourself bodily (like someone diving into water) behind something or into e.g. a hole or trench, so that you are safe (or safer than before) from being seen by someone, or, very often, hit by bullets when someone is shooting at you. It is something that soldiers in battle often do.